# How to Remove SVG from WordPress header

Tags: wordpress

I am seeing this too:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility:...

Looks to be related to duo tone things, which I am not using.

How to remove this from wordpress theme

Answer of my question

Comment: Can you list the theme and plugins you are using? or even a link.  By default, WordPress shouldn't add unnecessary SVG within its code. You've also just put in a bit of the SVG, maybe post the whole svg code and update your answer

Answer (score 0):

I would need a few more informations: What website? If you don't want to publish it, what plugins and themes? You can use brackets to search for the string or allegedly php myadmin (sometimes these things are in FTP but in most cases in database). Then you can try out to delete the string and check if everything works. Don't forget to backup your website

Comment: You can add this as comment instead of answer

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_global_styles' );
remove_action( 'wp_body_open', 'wp_global_styles_render_svg_filters' );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_block_css', 100 );

function remove_block_css() {
   wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library' ); // Wordpress core
   wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library-theme' ); // Wordpress core
   wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-block-style' ); // WooCommerce
   wp_dequeue_style( 'storefront-gutenberg-blocks' ); // Storefront theme
}
```